# Submit multipart/form-data?

Tags: c#, post, httpwebrequest, webclient, webrequest

I've Googl-ed/SO'd to death and still nothing seems to work for me. Everything has submitted fine except for the file. I've tried so many things I don't even have the original code prior to trying to get this darn file to transmit. I've tried WebClient, HttpWebRequest, etc. Nothing. I must be missing something trivial. Thanks.

1. What should I be using for a class? WebClient? HttpWebRequest?
2. What method should I be using to upload values. (I don't really care about parsing a response.)
3. How do I get the file into the request? From what I understand I should get the bytes and add them to the NameValueCollection of parameters I already have?

   ```
       if (File.Exists(filepath))
           using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
           {
               new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read).CopyTo(ms);
               return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
           }
   ```

Comment: Can you clarify. You are submitting a multi-part form data from C# code? Or are you trying to read a multi-part form submit?

Comment: This is a bit vague. What are you trying to do ? Work with a file that was uploaded from a web form ?